# How to use Scrapy to parse PDFs without a specific .pdf-link?

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I try to download PDFs but in case of https://ratsinformation.stadt-koeln.de/si0057.asp?__ksinr=23723 I see no `.pdf` links which could be grabbed by Scrapy. This example shows the missing .pdf in the URL https://ratsinformation.stadt-koeln.de/getfile.asp?id=850608&type=do.

Is Scrapy also able to handle `getfile.asp` links to detect the file itself?

This is the approach to get all the pdf links on a specific page:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline


class PdfPipeline(FilesPipeline):
    # to save with the name of the pdf from the website instead of hash
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        file_name = request.url.split('/')[-1]
        return file_name


class StadtKoelnAmtsblattSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stadt_koeln_amtsblatt'
    start_urls = ['https://ratsinformation.stadt-koeln.de/si0057.asp?__ksinr=23723']

    custom_settings = {
        "ITEM_PIPELINES": {
            PdfPipeline: 100
        },
        "FILES_STORE": "downloaded_files"
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-blue']/@href").getall()
        links = [response.urljoin(link) for link in links]  # to make them absolute urls

        yield {
            "file_urls": links
        }
```

I am receiving an error for each of the attempts to download the files.

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'downloaded_files\\getfile.asp?id=821665&type=do'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by the `PdfPipeline` because the url does not have the filename so you have to obtain the filename in the `parse` method and then capture the name in the pipeline like below.

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline


class PdfPipeline(FilesPipeline):
    # to save with the name of the pdf from the website instead of hash
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, *, item=None):
        return item["filename"]


class StadtKoelnAmtsblattSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stadt_koeln_amtsblatt'
    start_urls = ['https://ratsinformation.stadt-koeln.de/si0057.asp?__ksinr=23723']

    custom_settings = {
        "ITEM_PIPELINES": {
            PdfPipeline: 100
        },
        "FILES_STORE": "downloaded_files",
        "USER_AGENT": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.80 Safari/537.36"
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        for i, item in enumerate(response.xpath("//a[contains(@title, 'Dokument Download')]")):
            title = item.xpath("./text()").get()
            urls = item.xpath("./@href").getall()
            if title:
                yield {
                    "filename": title + str(i) + ".pdf",# to take care of duplicated file names
                    "file_urls": [response.urljoin(url) for url in urls]
                }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The learning curve is really steep when starting with Scrapy...

Comment: After I tested the solution I would like to mention two points. When I do ```scrapy crawl botname -o metadata.json``` I see 24 entries with status downloaded but in the download folder I only see 21 files. On the webpage I also see 24 download buttons. Second, one of these files is a 0 byte file called "ACHTUNG". I guess Scrapy struggled to download the file "ACHTUNG: Hinweise Infektionsschutz Gremiensitzungen 3G 25.08.2021". But most of the files are downloaded perfectly. Do you have an idea what happened?

Comment: I guess Scrapy has a problem with different pdfs sharing the same title name. Two files with the same title are downloaded and in the download folder I see that one letter is missing. Maybe Scrapy does that automatically? On the other hand: One file called "Mitteilung Ausschuss" is downloaded (https://ratsinformation.stadt-koeln.de/getfile.asp?id=835762&type=do) but the second file "Mitteilung Ausschuss" isn't (https://ratsinformation.stadt-koeln.de/getfile.asp?id=821323&type=do). I can also open a new question on Stackoverflow if you want :)

Comment: No need for another question. Scrapy checks if a file is already downloaded so that it doesn't download it again. If they have the same checksum then scrapy will not download the second file. You can add a check in the `parse` method and maybe assign a new name with a sequence if a file is already downloaded. I have edited the answer so that in the parse method, scrapy adds the index number to the filename so that they are unique. I get 24 results. Also check if your internet speed if fast enough

Comment: Now I also have 24 items but the file with filename starting with "Achtung: ..." isn't downloaded. I guess it's because on Windows pdf files cannot have a ":" in the file name. I included ```if ":" in title: title = title.replace(":", "-")``` before yield the results and it works.